# java.util.prefs.Preferences Sharing between two JVMs

Tags: java

I have two java programs (*A*, *B*) that run in separate (local) JVMs, but access the same java.util.prefs.Preferences (java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences)

```
prefs = Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(Foo.class)
```

Both programs call this once at startup.

*A* is a GUI program which allows configuration. Changes are written to the Preferences node. At the end `flush` is called.

*B* is a background program that is doing the actual work.

*A* sends a notification to *B* that the configuration has changed. *B* reads the changed configuration.

There is no concurrent access to the preferences, since Cross-JVM  locking (using `java.nio.channels.FileLock`) is used.

My Question: Is this a safe solution? Will *B* always read what *A* has written?

Comment: of course - as long as you actually call flush and maybe verify that the file has been written correctly it will always be readable by anything which has  FS-permissions. In any other case your JVM is compromised or the operating system doesnt work.

Comment: Because I'm on Windows, the Registry is used for the Preferences. The FileLock is just used to prevent concurrent access between the two JVMs 
I've already tested this implementation, but get some strange Errors: When A deletes a node, B is still "seeing" this node. After that, when children of this node are accessed I get "WARNING: Trying to recreate Windows registry node ..." errors.

Comment: Windows registry = files. If your nodes are visible after deletion there are only two possible explanations : java.util.prefs is a buggy package OR your code does not lock/write/flush/unlock correctly. Im gonna place my highest bet on the second horse. Btw : you cant know if the registry is used until you explicitly test it at each application runtime, please read the javadoc.

Comment: JavaDoc says: "If this class is used concurrently by multiple JVMs that store their preference data in the same backing store, the data store will not be corrupted, but no other guarantees are made concerning the consistency of the preference data."

Comment: correct. I think its best to start practising Java with simple application designs at first - concurrency is quite the advanced topic ... it can lead to much confusion and make the learning curve much more steep if the order of learning experiences is wrong. For instance, if your concurrently-used objects are not updated automatically you will need to re-read the underlying data structures all by yourself ... even changelisteners most likely are bound to your JVM-scope hence once will be updated inside of itself, external changes might not be catched; thats why one needs file locks sometimes.

Comment: I've written enough applications using concurrency and locks, but use the Preferences API rather seldom. 

In my case only JVM 1 is writing, JVM 2 is reading. Every change is reflected after flush instantly. But if I call "remove" on a Node, followed by flush, it's still there for JVM 2. I call this a bug.

Comment: Well in that case you'd be the only person on the planet - but feel free to open a bugreport .... and watch it being closed again.